# Loading specfic account data after login with Meteor package

Tags: meteor

I'm just getting started with the Meteor framework.  I had a look for a package that would help with the login functionality.

I found this:
www.atmospherejs.com/package/accounts-entry

My question is, once logged in, how would I then load the account for the user?  I expect I'll need to use some sort of "username" field to look up other data.  Once the user has logged in I'd want to redirect the user to a "My Account" section where specific account data is loaded.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor has a shortcut function for getting information about the current user.

```
var currentUser = Meteor.user();
```

There is also a built-in template helper.

```
<template name="main">
  {{#if currentUser}}
  {{> myaccount}}
  {{else}}
  {{> signin}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

By default, it will send username, emails, and profile. If you want additional fields, you'll need to publish/subscribe to that data separately.

See the accounts section of the docs for more information: http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's really helpful.  I'll take a look at the accounts section of the docs.  Hopefully I can make sense of it :)

Answer (score 0):

As for every MongoDB object Meteor uses it's own id for the users as well. The **ID for the current user** is available as

```
Meteor.userId()
```

The whole **user object** for the current user can be found by using:

```
Meteor.user()
```

This user object contains an object called "profile" which is a good place to store additional user profile data.

Besides that, Meteor provides the whole user collection the the clients. It can be used to **find any user**, e.g. by it's user id. That would look like this:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: "qLjxQBad5vN9Z6cdn"})
```

or list the whole users collection:

```
Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
```

I would suggest you try these commands in your a browser's javascript console.

Later on when you enable **security** in your app (i.e. disable autopublish) you might want to control which fields of the user
objects are published to the clients, e.g. to keep users' email adresses private. This would be an example that publishes only the profile object but not the emails:

```
Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: { profile: 1}});
});
```